# Is it possible to add Facebook social comment in android app without using HTML

Tags: android, facebook-social-plugins

In my Android application, without using HTML need to insert facebook social comment. I searched but everywhere social comments have been inserted using html tags.

Comment: You can use Graph API to get social feed and then parse json and display comment according to you.

Comment: Will you pls give me related links if u have...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ and click on Profile feed (Wall) link

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava i have same problem. Can you explain more details about this solution?
It must have a post on my wall to add comment on it?

Comment: Did you got the answer for your question, as I am now facing the same issue.